# Rails - How to create a dynamic homepage that displays blog posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm struggling to set up a website's homepage that contains a blog section.

The blog section will have its own model + controller, but my question is:

1. How do I display the blog posts from this model to my homepage which currently is a static page (only has controller and view)?

These would be the routes:

```
root "pages#home"
get "pages" => "pages#home", as: :pages

get "blog" => "blogs#index", as: :blogs
get "blog/new" => "blogs#new", as: :new_blog
get "blog/:id" => "blogs#show", as: :blog
post "blog" => "blogs#create"
get "blog/:id/edit" => "blogs#edit", as: :edit_blog
patch "blog/:id" => "blogs#update"
delete "blog/:id" => "blogs#destroy"
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have and anything you tried. For example, any answer will depend on the static pages controller name and method name so can you post that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the variable in the controllers action that you want to show the blogs in, once you do that then the view will have access to it.

pages_controller.rb (Or whatever the pages controller's exact name is)

```
def home
  @blogs = Blog.all
end
```

Then in the view you can do this

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  <%= blog.title %> <!-- Or whatever you want to show, the html here depends on your needs
<% end %>
```

That should solve the issue for you.

Comment: Normally controller file names are lower-case, like `pages_controller.rb`. A minor point, but using the wrong naming will cause confusing problems.

Comment: I feel silly, but I didn't realize you could access classes/models outside. (everything makes sense now!)